# Как в цикле посчитать количество повторов в строке? Python

Tags: python, for

Работаю с апи одного проекта и у меня проблема в том, что когда я в цикле прохожусь по словарю чтобы создать более менее нормальный текст, то у меня куча повторов, как мне их убрать и оставить всего один екземпляр текста, а рядом в скобках написать количество, показываю код:

```
result = ''

for i in resp['Items']:

    title = 'Название: '+i['Title'] + '\n'

    price = 'Цена: '+ str(i['MarketPrice']['Amount']) + '$\n'

    result += '\n'+title+price+'------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Что получаю:

```
Название: Snakebite Case
Цена на Dmarket: 0.1$
------------------------------------------------------------
Название: Horizon Case
Цена на Dmarket: 0.17$
------------------------------------------------------------
Название: Prisma Case
Цена на Dmarket: 0.12$
------------------------------------------------------------
Название: Sticker | Ancient Beast
Цена на Dmarket: 0.09$
------------------------------------------------------------
Название: Snakebite Case
Цена на Dmarket: 0.1$
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Как видите названия повторяются, я хочу совместить их и рядом в скобках указать количество например (x2)

Пример того что хочу увидеть:

```
    Название: Snakebite Case (х2)
    Цена на Dmarket: 0.1$
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Название: Horizon Case
    Цена на Dmarket: 0.17$
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Название: Prisma Case
    Цена на Dmarket: 0.12$
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Название: Sticker | Ancient Beast
    Цена на Dmarket: 0.09$
    ------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Как выглядит схема**

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "AssetID": "string",
      "VariantID": "string",
      "Title": "string",
      "ImageURL": "string",
      "GameID": "string",
      "GameType": "GameTypeBlockchain",
      "Location": "AssetLocationInGame",
      "Withdrawable": true,
      "Depositable": true,
      "Tradable": true,
      "Attributes": [
        {
          "Name": "string",
          "Value": "string"
        }
      ],
      "Offer": {
        "OfferID": "string",
        "Price": {
          "Currency": "string",
          "Amount": 0
        },
        "Fee": {
          "Currency": "string",
          "Amount": 0
        },
        "CreatedDate": "string"
      },
      "MarketPrice": {
        "Currency": "string",
        "Amount": 0
      },
      "InstantPrice": {
        "Currency": "string",
        "Amount": 0
      },
      "ClassID": "string"
    }
  ],
  "Total": "string",
  "Cursor": "string"
}
```

Comment: в словарь вы добавите в вопрос или нам телепатией заняться?

Comment: Через `Counter` посчитать. Но да, для нормального кода давайте воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Добавил пример того что хочу увидеть

Comment: Добавьте ещё пример самого словаря всё-таки

Comment: Я не совсем понял что нужно добавить, у меня парсинг json

Comment: Добавил схему json

Comment: Здравствуйте Kowl, хотел сказать что оформление вопроса в будущем должно выглядеть именно таким, что-бы дать разработчику полное понимание того что вы хотите сделать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте Kowl *ещё раз!*, внёс одну малейшую поправочку в 'title', **каждый 'title' имеет стартовую единицу (x1)**, которая **инкрементируется при условии, что 'title' уже есть в вашей строке результата**

```
result = ''
for item in items:
    if item["Title"] in result:
        count = int(result[result.index(item['Title']) + len(item["Title"]) + 3])
        result = result.replace(f"{item['Title']} (x{count})", f"{item['Title']} (x{count+1})")
        continue
    title = f"Название: {item['Title']} (x1)\n"
    price = f"Цена: {item['MarketPrice']['Amount']}$\n"
    result += "\n" + title + price + ("-" * 60)
```

**По вашей просьбе убрал стартовый х1**

```
result = ''
for item in items:
    if item["Title"] in result:
        count = result[result.index(item['Title']) + len(item["Title"]) + 3]
        if count.isdigit():
            count = int(count)
            result = result.replace(f"{item['Title']} (x{count})", f"{item['Title']} (x{count+1})")
            continue
        result = result.replace(f"{item['Title']}", f"{item['Title']} (x{2})")
        continue
    title = f"Название: {item['Title']}\n"
    price = f"Цена: {item['MarketPrice']['Amount']}$\n"
    result += "\n" + title + price + ("-" * 60)
```

Comment: Если можно убрать х1, так будет более лучше, спасибо)

Comment: По вашей просьбе убрал х1

Comment: Если в двух записях будет один заголовок но разные цены, одна из цен будет потеряна?

Comment: Полно текстовый поиск (`item["Title"] in result`) - плохая идея. Разные данные могу привести к ошибкам. Медленно.

Comment: Stanislav Volodarskiy, я тоже думал об этом, но по поводу ценника уточнений не было, извиняюсь не подумал, по поводу поиска, я +- разработчик, ещё зелён, спасибо за комментарий буду учиться !

Comment: Тут просто повезло что под каждый заголовок цена та же, то-есть яблоко стоит 1 доллар то оно везде будет стоить 1 доллар

Comment: Да видишь, если ты уверен что тут все под одной ценой тогда почему бы не ограничиться такой записью но в любом случае поиск в целой строке рез. плохая идея :(

Answer (score 2):

Собрать все записи в группы с одинаковыми заголовками и ценами. Распечатать группы:

```
import collections


def report(resp):

    def records():
        c = collections.Counter(
            (i['Title'], i['MarketPrice']['Amount']) for i in resp['Items']
        )
        for (title, price), amount in c.items():
            factor = f' (x{amount})' if amount > 1 else ''
            line1 = f'Название: {title}{factor}'
            line2 = f'Цена: {price}$'
            yield f'{line1}\n{line2}'

    spacer = '-' * 60
    return f'\n{spacer}\n'.join(records())


print(report({
    'Items': [
        { 'Title': 'Snakebite Case', 'MarketPrice': { 'Amount': 0.1 } },
        { 'Title': 'Horizon Case', 'MarketPrice': { 'Amount': 0.17 } },
        { 'Title': 'Prisma Case', 'MarketPrice': { 'Amount': 0.12 } },
        { 'Title': 'Sticker | Ancient Beast', 'MarketPrice': { 'Amount': 0.09 } },
        { 'Title': 'Snakebite Case', 'MarketPrice': { 'Amount': 0.1 } }
    ]
}))
```

> ```
> Название: Snakebite Case (x2)
> Цена: 0.1$
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> Название: Horizon Case
> Цена: 0.17$
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> Название: Prisma Case
> Цена: 0.12$
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> Название: Sticker | Ancient Beast
> Цена: 0.09$
> ```

Comment: Спасибо вам за опыт, 113 по сравнению с 21.6к рейтинга, я думаю для уровня как я мой ответ был всё же не идеален т.к. я не учитывал одинаковую цену 'item' -а